# Image manipulation in Parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a simple table in Parse:

[image]

I want to get the photo column, process the file and then save it in the coverPhoto column. This is what I got:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testPhoto", function(request, response) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("ItemPhoto")
  query.get("62EmHGTb33", {
    success: function(object) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.setData(object.get('photo'));
      image.scale({
        width: 250
      });
      image.setFormat("JPEG");
      var base64 = image.toString("base64");
      var cropped = new Parse.File("cover.jpg", { base64: base64 });
      object.set("coverPhoto", cropped);

      object.save(null, {
        success: function(isave) {
          response.success("OK");
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
          response.error(error);
        }
      });

      //response.success(object.get('photo').url());
    },

    error: function(object, error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });

});
```

I'm getting an error I don't know how to fix: `{"code":141,"error":"{\"code\":107,\"message\":\"base64 field cannot be decoded\"}"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse images already have `base64` representation, it looks like:

`image.data().base64`